# Nodes in the air column are not always acting as nodes?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

There are many representations of a standing wave column in lets say open-open instrument like flute. In this case one node centrally, and 2 anti-nodes at the openings. However, nowhere do they explain the process of how node is created.
My guess is that the first pressure wave we blow through the flute ripples all the way through it, moving the air molecules that would be nodes as well. Only when the wave reaches the anti-node molecules and they spring back due to elasticity (or is it newly generated pressure difference in the pipe due to speed of air?) - a new pressure wave is coming back towards the middle, hopefully hitting the new wave from our mouth if the frequency is right. The node molecules might not be in their "default" state just yet, but as the external forces are canceled out they are free to come back slowly due to their elasticity when the previous input of energy wears out.

My guess is that the similar pattern of events happens for the nodes of the harmonics as well, except that the harmonic nodes are never 100% inert, but the lower-harmonic-nodes have small wiggle room, and as we go higher they have more and more movement but never fully as anti-nodes of the fundamental.
So the standing wave takes time to be established as such and until then the nodes of the fundamental move. And the harmonics' nodes arise in time as well,
Is this correct? Hope that makes some sense explained in the layman fashion. :D
Thanks a lot, cheers!

Comment: Well, yes,  steady-state solutions differ from dynamic "start-up" varying conditions.

Comment: Aha. So is the above correct on how it goes down, especially for the harmonics' nodes budging a bit more (more frequently probably than more displacement) than the node of the fundamental?
Also does the fundamental node still move a little? Even though everywhere they say it's standing still, I don't get how it can pass on kinetic energy if it's standing still...

Comment: @Dimitri Strictly speaking, standing waves are *not* waves, exactly due to the fact that there is no energy propagation from one place of the pattern to others. Of course this hold only for the oversimplified cases introductory texts deal with. This may a bit counter-intuitive since a standing wave, first of all is termed "wave", and secondly it is formed of two traveling waves.

Comment: But practically speaking, if we take for example a air column in a trumpet: I am inputting energy at one end and it ends up at the other end, obviously via air inside it. So the whole idea of nodes not moving at all has got to be false, unless they work in place by accumulating force and discharging it via elasticity, without moving?

Comment: @dmitri your trumpet has an anti-node somewhere near the end of the bell, so the energy there does escape into the external atmosphere.  There is an impedance-matching task there, which is why instruments have bells.